# what value will be printed out if it is out of range in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am a rookie in C++ and I have got a question here.

I use an int to print the first 100 power of 2. I know that the outcome will be out of range of an int variable. I am just curious since the result given by the program is 0. How did 0 come out?

Thanks in advance!

My code is as followed:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int a=1;
    unsigned int b=1;

    for (int i=1;i<=100;i++)     
    { 
        a=2*a;
        b=2*b;
    }

    cout<<"the first 1oo powers of 2 is (using an signed int): "<<a<<endl;
    cout<<"the first 1oo powers of 2 is (using an unsigned int): "<<b<<endl;

    //The fix
    cout<<"Enter a Char to Exit."<<endl;
    char theFix;
    cin>>theFix;
}
```

Comment: you need to show your code if you want an accurate answer

Comment: Unsigned integral types operate modulo 2ⁿ, where n is the width of the type in bits.

Comment: Now you've posted the code: `b=2*b` only happens once, since you forgot to enclose the loop body in braces. That's why `b` ends up as 2.

Comment: @devdot, It's not buffer overflow, it's integer overflow, and there really is no overflow with unsigned types because of the modulo rules.

Comment: @chris I was looking for this in the standard, and much to my surprise I can't find it. Sure, *converting* to unsigned wraps modulo (4.7/2), but if an expression overflows, 5/4 apparently makes it all undefined.

Comment: @Angew, See §3.9.1 [basic.fundamental]/4.

Comment: Thanks for the comments above. Thanks @MikeSeymour. It is due to my carelessness that the previous outcome of b is 2. Actually, both outcomes in VS 2010 is 0. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you're new to C++, you might not know how the computer stores information. Eventually, all integers are broken down into 32-bit binary numbers (a bunch of 1's and 0's).

```
a = a * 2; // multiplication

a << 1;    // left shift
```

These two instructions are actually synonymous due to the nature of binary numbers.

For instance, 0....000010 in binary notation == 2 in decimal notation.

So,

> ```
> 2 * 2 = 4  = 0....000100
> 4 * 2 = 8  = 0....001000
> 8 * 2 = 16 = 0....010000
> ```
>
> and so on...

Since the bit count is capped at 32 for integers, you'll get a huge number 2^32 == 1000....000. When you multiply by 2 again, the number is shifted left again and you end up with 000...000000 = 0.

All further multiplications of 0 = zero, so that's where your final result came from.

EDIT: Would just like to point out that this is one of the only situations where this exact result would occur. If you were to try using the number 3, for example, you would see the expected integer overflow behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Multiplying an unsigned integer or a positive signed integer by 2 is like shifting left by 1, while a 0 bit will be shifted in from the right. After 32 iterations (assuming 32 bit integers), the entire value will be all 0 bits. After that, shifting 0 left will not change the outcome anymore.